# Canon sdk internal error at edsDownload

Tags: canon-sdk

I have internal error at the EdsDownload. I'am using EOS 1100D without sdcard. The Canon sample code (CameraContorol) can download image. Used SDK: 2.13 and 2.12 (i have same problem with both). Please help me.
Note: the "picture000x.jpg" size is 0 after the run (because the EdsCreateFileStream call).

**My code output**:
Device name: Canon EOS 1100D.
GET PICTURE:
'Call' handleObjectEvent.
Event: kEdsStateEvent_JobStatusChanged,
Event code: 770

                          Internal error at EdsDownload.
 stream != NULL
Download h.ended.
Press key to quit.

**My code**:

```
bool getPictureEnabled = false,
     hasCamera = false;
EdsCameraRef camera;
EdsImageRef picture;
volatile EdsUInt32 bufferSize;

EdsError DownloadImage(EdsDirectoryItemRef directoryItem);
```

handleSateEvent:

```
EdsError EDSCALLBACK handleSateEvent(EdsStateEvent event, EdsUInt32 parameter, EdsVoid * context) {
    switch(event) {
    case kEdsStateEvent_CaptureError:
        printf("Event: kEdsStateEvent_CaptureError,\n");
        throw "Camera capture error.";

    case kEdsStateEvent_JobStatusChanged:
        printf("Event: kEdsStateEvent_JobStatusChanged,\n");
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    printf("Event code: %d.\n", (int)event);

    return EDS_ERR_OK;
}
```

handleObjectEvent:

```
EdsError EDSCALLBACK handleObjectEvent(EdsObjectEvent event, EdsBaseRef object, EdsVoid * context) {
    if(event == kEdsObjectEvent_DirItemCreated || event == kEdsObjectEvent_DirItemRequestTransfer || event == kEdsObjectEvent_DirItemRequestTransferDT) {
        if(!getPictureEnabled)  {
            printf("object event handler: FALSE alert\n");
            if(object) EdsRelease(object);
            return EDS_ERR_OK;
        }
        //EdsRetain(object);
        DownloadImage(object);
    }

    if(object) EdsRelease(object);

    return EDS_ERR_OK;
}
```

main function:

```
int main(int parC, char *pars[]) {
    int processCounter = 0;
    EdsCameraListRef eclr;
    EdsError edsError = EdsInitializeSDK();
    if(edsError)  {
        printf("I can't initialize the Eds sdk.\n");
        goto stop;
    }

    processCounter = 1;
    edsError = EdsGetCameraList(&eclr);
    if(edsError)  {
        printf("I can't get the camera list.\n");
        goto stop;
    }

    processCounter = 2;
    EdsUInt32 camCount;
    edsError = EdsGetChildCount(eclr, &camCount);
    if(edsError)  {
        printf("I can't read the camera count.\n");
        goto stop;
    }

    hasCamera = camCount > 0;
    if(!hasCamera)  {
        printf("There is no camera in the list.\n");
        goto stop;
    }

    edsError = EdsGetChildAtIndex(eclr, 0, &camera);
    if(edsError)  {
        printf("I can't get the camera.\n");
        goto stop;
    }

    edsError = EdsSetCameraStateEventHandler(camera, kEdsStateEvent_All, handleSateEvent, NULL);
    if(edsError) printf("Error at EdsSetCameraStateEventHandler.\n");

    edsError = EdsSetObjectEventHandler(camera, kEdsObjectEvent_All, handleObjectEvent, NULL);
    if(edsError)  {
        printf("Error at EdsSetObjectEventHandler.\n");
        goto stop;
    }

    edsError = EdsOpenSession(camera);
    if(edsError)  {
        printf("I can't open the session.\n");
        goto stop;
    }

    processCounter = 3;

    EdsDeviceInfo outDeviceInfo;
    edsError = EdsGetDeviceInfo(camera, &outDeviceInfo);
    if(edsError) printf("I can't get device info.\n");
    else printf("Device name: %s.\n", (char *) outDeviceInfo.szDeviceDescription);

    EdsUInt32 saveTo = kEdsSaveTo_Host;
    edsError = EdsSetPropertyData(camera, kEdsPropID_SaveTo, 0, sizeof(EdsUInt32) , &saveTo);
    if(edsError != EDS_ERR_OK) printf("Error at EdsSetPropertyData -> kEdsSaveTo.\n");

    EdsCapacity capacity = {0x7FFFFFFF, 0x1000, 1};
    edsError = EdsSetCapacity(camera, capacity);
    if(edsError != EDS_ERR_OK) printf("Error at EdsSetPropertyData -> kEdsSaveTo.\n");

    printf("GET PICTURE:\n");
    getPictureEnabled = true;
    edsError = EdsSendCommand(camera, kEdsCameraCommand_TakePicture , 0);

    if(edsError) printf("ERROR: Take picture.\n");
    else { //handleObjectEvent "call":
        printf("'Call' handleObjectEvent.\n");
        edsError = EdsCloseSession(camera);
        if(edsError) printf("I can't close the session 1.\n");

        edsError = EdsOpenSession(camera);
        if(edsError) printf("I can't open the session 2.\n");
    }

stop:
    printf("Press key to quit...\n");
    getchar();

    switch (processCounter) {

    case 3:
        edsError = EdsCloseSession(camera);
        if(edsError) printf("I can't close the session 2.\n");

    case 2:
        edsError = EdsRelease(eclr);
        if(edsError) printf("I can't release eds cam. list.\n");

    case 1:
        EdsTerminateSDK();

    default: break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

DownloadImage function:

```
EdsError DownloadImage(EdsDirectoryItemRef directoryItem) {
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED ); //i tried without this, and don't screen change

    EdsError err;
    EdsStreamRef stream = NULL;

    EdsDirectoryItemInfo dirItemInfo;
    err = EdsGetDirectoryItemInfo(directoryItem, &dirItemInfo);

    if(err == EDS_ERR_OK) {
        err = EdsCreateFileStream(dirItemInfo.szFileName, kEdsFileCreateDisposition_CreateAlways, kEdsAccess_ReadWrite, &stream);
        if(err != EDS_ERR_OK) printf("ERROR: EdsCreateFileStream.\n");
        bufferSize = dirItemInfo.size; 
        //EdsSetProgressCallback(stream, ProgressFunc, kEdsProgressOption_Periodically, NULL);
    }
    else printf("ERROR 1\n");

    //err = EdsSendStatusCommand(camera, kEdsCameraStatusCommand_UILock, 0); //i tried with this, and don't screen change
    //err = EdsSendStatusCommand(camera, kEdsCameraStatusCommand_EnterDirectTransfer, 0); //i tried with this, and don't screen change
    if(err) {
        printf("ERROR: transfer lock.\n");
    }//*/

    //if(err == EDS_ERR_OK)
    //do
    //{
        err = EdsDownload(directoryItem, dirItemInfo.size, stream); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM: EDS_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR! (after that row: err = 2)
    //}
    //while(err != EDS_ERR_OK);//*/
    if(err == EDS_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR) printf("\n\t\tInternal error at EdsDownload.\n");

    //if(err == EDS_ERR_OK)
    {
        err = EdsDownloadComplete(directoryItem);
    }

    // Release stream
    if( stream != NULL) {
        EdsCreateImageRef(stream, &picture);
        EdsRelease(stream);
        stream = NULL;
        printf(" stream != NULL\n");
    }

    //err = EdsSendStatusCommand(camera, kEdsCameraStatusCommand_ExitDirectTransfer, 0); //i tried with this, and don't screen change
    //err = EdsSendStatusCommand(camera, kEdsCameraStatusCommand_UIUnLock, 0); //i tried with this, and don't screen change
    if(err) {
        printf("ERROR: transfer lock.\n");
        return NULL;
    }//*/
    printf("Download ended.\n");

    CoUninitialize(); //i tried without this, and don't screen change
    return err;
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty hefty block of code you've got there!  You may want to consider condensing it down to just show the DownloadImage function in order to highlight the lines at the end that cause the error, it can be tough to parse though lots of code just to get to the meat of an issue.

Comment: Do you have the exception/error itself?

Comment: There isn't any exception and error, just the Internal error at the "edsDownload" and the JobStatusChanged event.

Comment: The code is big, i know, but earlier i searched the problem resolution at the google, and many resolutions was there, but these (main: kEdsSaveTo_Host, EdsSetCapacity, EdsSetObjectEventHandler, ...) are in my code. There are four function. The 2 eventHandler (handleSateEvent and handleObjectEvent), the main code (with the sdk and camera init/release calls), and finally the DownloadImage code. I try to put some highlight, but in the code: it doesn't working. (It is my first question, but i searching the possibilities.)

Comment: I think the main code is important. I had a problem earlier: without the '//handleObjectEvent "call":' block (in main) the handleObjectEvent not called or called immediately after the EdsSetObjectEventHandler add the event.

Comment: I seperated the functions.

Comment: I hope, if the code will working: the all code will usefull to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to All!
I have the solution. This is not in the sdk document.
[Here is](http://songuke.blogspot.hu/2012/05/short-note-about-using-canon-edsdk.html)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891693/taking-picture-with-edsdk-and-retrieving-it-immediately). This problem exists, if you are using Windows operation system.
The concrete solution:

```
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL))
    {        
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }
```

I will fix the code, erease the unecessary comments and it will working to everyone! (Soon.)

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the call for "EdsCreateFileStream", especially the first parameter ? According to the docs "It creates a new file on a host computer (or opens an existing file) and creates a file stream for access to the file." The first parameter should be a local, accessible file path (e.g. "C:\tmp.jpg" on windows), and from quickly looking at this it might be you don't specify this correctly. Could you print this?

Comment: Thank you your answer. The first parameter is "IMG_0001.JPG" sometimes (sometimes: "IMG_0002.JPG".. etc ). It is generated next to the cpp and header files (if it run in the VS environment). If i delete the file, and run again the program: the error is same, and generate the file with 0 length again.
"kEdsFileCreateDisposition_CreateAlways - Creates a new file. If the designated file already exists, that file is overwritten and existing attributes is erased." (doc) <br>
Maybe the read and write attribute is not lucky, but i tried with kEdsAccess_Write, and there isn't any changes.

Comment: ok, that sounds ok. Could you try with EdsCreateMemoryStream instead of EdsCreateFileStream? To be sure, could you make sure the "saveTo" is of type EdsSaveTo, and also use sizeof(EdsSaveTo). If this also doesn't work, there is always the possibility of issues with your build environment (linking to the right DLLs). I cannot help here because I use osX and not Windows.

Comment: I tried the EdsCreateMemoryStream, and the internal error stayed. saveTo is an EdsUInt32 type and at the document is this type too. The size's type is EdsUInt32 not int. I correct this, but there is the same problem. I am watch the dll idea. Thank you your time!