# EDSDK event to detect taken pictures

Tags: c#, edsdk, canon-sdk

I have a `Canon EOS 1100D (Rebel T3)` and wrote a C# program to control it using the [`EDSDK`](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/sdk_homepage) `dlls`. I'm saving taken pictures on the computer.

I want to take pictures remotely by a "Wireless Shutter Release Remote Controller", and then process these pictures immediately. But there is a problem:

Is there any event in `EDSDK dlls` that can detect newly captured photos? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Mind sharing some code... also need to capture the moment a picture is taken.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you should

- init the camera connection and session through USB
- set kEdsPropID_SaveTo to kEdsSaveTo_Host or kEdsSaveTo_Both
- register an object event handler with the EDSDK
- wait for a kEdsObjectEvent_DirItemRequestTransfer event
- execute or cancel the downloading of the image (DownloadComplete (after downloading) or CancelDownload (if images are not needed))

for C# specific examples, see other posts like [Canon sdk internal error at edsDownload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738575/canon-sdk-internal-error-at-edsdownload)